# Java output image bad quality in browser

Tags: java

I'm trying to write the inputstream image to OutputStream to display the image in the browser this is the code:

```
try
{
    InputStream input = Filer.readImage("images/test.jpg");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1)
    {
        responseBody.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}
catch(IOException e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

the readImage:

```
public static InputStream readImage(String file) throws IOException {
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);

    return input;

}
```

This is the original image:

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQzVG.jpg]

This is the output after the above procedure:

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgaKF.jpg]

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to close the output stream:

```
InputStream input = Filer.readImage("images/test.jpg");
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    responseBody.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
responseBody.close(); // <-----------
```

Comment: ahh, didn't knew that, thank you very much, accept answer in 7 minutes

Comment: if you close the `responseBody` in the `finally` block of your try-catch, it'll be closed even in case of an error